# Create a list of paginated formatted URLs from list of results

Tags: c#, .net, grouping, paging

I have a set of results that I would like to be paginated for a page on a c#, dotnet website.

The first set contains only 22 results *(Because there will be something else visually taking up the space of two of these results on the first page's layout)*.

each subsequent set contains 24 results.

Id like to generate a list URLs that look like this:-

```
"/result-set/1/0/21",
"/result-set/2/22/46",
"/result-set/3/47/71"
```

And so on...
Where the first number represents the page number, the second a start index and the third an end index that doesn't exceed the total number of records.

I can seem to get the math right and I've made it harder for myself with the first set having a smaller amount in it.

One approach is to skip the first 22 results and to manually add that to the top of the list.

Perhaps if someone could recommend a good library? because I'm possibly re-inventing the wheel here. The ones that I have found seem to be integrated with Entity Framework.

Comment: For some reason I can't seem to get my head around it! I'm getting examples like 2/22/46, 3/46/68.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function to calculate the indexes, with page No. as input.

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    
    public static (int, int) GetIndexes(int pageNum) {
        if (pageNum <= 1)
            return (0, 21);
            
        int toAdd = (pageNum-2) * 25;
        return (22 + toAdd, 46 + toAdd);
    }
    
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(GetIndexes(1));
        Console.WriteLine(GetIndexes(2));
        Console.WriteLine(GetIndexes(3));
        Console.WriteLine(GetIndexes(4));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is much more elegant that what I've come up with. Thank you.